# Counting None values using lambda function

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array consisting of a bunch values, where some of them are Nan and the others are None. I want to count each of them. I can achieve this with a simple for loop as shown,

```
xx = np.array([2,3,4,None,np.nan,None])

count_None = 0
count_nan = 0
for i in xx:
    if i is None:
        count_None =+ 1
    if i is np.nan:
        count_nan =+ 1
```

I want to find out if I can achieve the same result in one line, perhaps using a lambda function. I tried writing it as so. But of course, the syntax is incorrect. Any ideas?

```
lambda xx: count_None =+1 if xx is None
```

Comment: If you can fix the title on this post, it will help other users find it. "Lambda" is misspelled as "labmda"

Comment: yea sure ofcourse :)
I am open to any suggestions on better titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving it as a one liner is :

```
len([i for i in xx if i is None])
# or the count function
xx.count(None)
```

or you can use the [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
np.count_nonzero(xx == None)
```

---

Using a lambda function, you can create a `list.count()` - like function:

```
>>> counter = lambda x,y:len([i for i in x if i == y])
>>> counter(xx,None)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a lambda but it creates a new list of just the None values and counts the length of that list.

```py
import numpy as np
xx = np.array([2,3,4,None,np.nan,None])
print(len([elem for elem in xx if elem is None]))
```

if you don't need it to be in numpy you can use the list count method

```py
xx = [2,3,4,None,np.nan,None]
print(xx.count(None))
```

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` is just a restricted format for creating a function.  It is 'one-line' and returns a value.  It should not be used for side effects.   You use of `counter += 1` is a side effect, so can't be use in a `lambda`.

A `lambda` that identifies the `None` values, can be used with `map`:

```
In [27]: alist = [2,3,4,None,np.nan,None]                                                              
In [28]: list(map(lambda x: x is None, alist))                                                         
Out[28]: [False, False, False, True, False, True]
```

`map` returns an iterable, which has to be expanded with `list`, or with `sum`:

```
In [29]: sum(map(lambda x: x is None, alist))                                                          
Out[29]: 2
```

But as others have shown, the list `count` method is simpler.

```
In [43]: alist.count(None)                                                                             
Out[43]: 2
In [44]: alist.count(np.nan)                                                                           
Out[44]: 1
```

An array containing `None` will be object `dtype`.  Iteration on such an array is slower than iteration on the list:

```
In [45]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                         
In [46]: arr                                                                                           
Out[46]: array([2, 3, 4, None, nan, None], dtype=object)
```

The array doesn't have the `count` method.  Also testing for `np.nan` is trickier.

```
In [47]: arr == None                                                                                   
Out[47]: array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True])
In [48]: arr == np.nan                                                                                 
Out[48]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False])
```

There is a `np.isnan` function, but that only works for `float` dtype arrays.

```
In [51]: arr.astype(float)                                                                             
Out[51]: array([ 2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan, nan])
In [52]: np.isnan(arr.astype(float))                                                                   
Out[52]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Answer (score 1):

A third approach:

```
>>> nan_count, none_count = np.sum([i is np.nan for i in xx]), np.sum([i is None for i in xx])
>>> print(nan_count, none_count)
1, 2
```

I'd tend to prefer two lines (one for each computation), but this works. It works by adding 1 for each True value, and 0 for each False value.

Another approach if you really want to use a lambda is to use `functools.reduce` which will perform the sum iteratively. Here, we start with a value of 0, and add 1 for each element that evaluates true:

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+(y is np.nan), xx, 0)
1
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+(y is None), xx, 0)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

> l= len(list(filter(lambda x:x is None, xx)))

It will return the number of NaN values. But the filter function will work with the list only.
You can use this approach if you want to use lambda.
I prefer using numpy function (np.count_nonzero)